# Adding another div

Tags: jquery, css

Hello I have here a hide/toggle div using jquery. I want to add another div `class="sidebar-toggle"`.

Below is the photo of sidebar open and close. The blue div is the `class="sidebar-toggle"` that I want to add, `class="sidebar-toggle"` is the link for hide/toggle div.

Here's my current output http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/

Sidebar-toggle Open

[image]

Sidebar-toggle Closed

[image]

Comment: where do you want to add it

Comment: @ArunPJohny just like in photo the blue one

Comment: "add a div" is pretty generic. Care to elaborate?

Comment: when do you  want to add  ?

Comment: I updated my question. sorry

Comment: [Like this....?](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/1/)

Comment: @NicholasHazel just like that. But I need just like in the picture. The blue div should be my link for hide/toggle div.

Comment: Piece of cake. Gimme one sec.

Comment: Just making sure. Like this but visible after close? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/2/)

Comment: @NicholasHazel yah it should be visible after close.

Comment: It should also open after close

Comment: Added a completely revamped code. You're making this too hard on yourself... minimized what you're looking for. View my `answer`. [Fiddle away to your heart's content](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/15/)

Answer (score 2):

### [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/13/)

Now, this is based on the discussions you did above, and the expected images you presented.

[image]

I used a bit of CSS and jQuery, although there are better ways to achieve this.

Note: Just use `z-index:3;` on `.sidebar-toggle` to make it clickable, all of it.

**CSS**

This was added to the `.sidebar-toggle` class.

```
left:33%;
top:0%;
position:fixed;
z-index:3;
```

**jQuery**

A bit of jQuery was used as well, for example, here's a snippet. The same for `else { }` with `0px;`

```
 $('.sidebar-toggle').animate({
        marginLeft: "-220px",
        opacity: "1"
      }, 'fast');
```

Comment: You should include your code in the question.  What happens when future users are looking for something like this, but jsfiddle is dead?

Comment: I was editing. Chill out brother :). You are right. I have always included code to take into account such factors, as you mentioned.

Comment: @AliGajani closed enough, but why is only the top part of .sidebar-toggle has the function of hide/toggle?

Comment: @user3097736 Because #maincontent is covering up the bar, and preventing the click from working, [this edit](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/11/) fixes that.

Comment: If you look at the code correctly, I am using one to move it to the left of -220px and then again in the else statement to bring it back to 0. This is creating the on/off effect.

Comment: I see a few issues. The code only works in the header for opening it back up.

Comment: Yes, I am incorporating what @Daedalus said to enable the whole bar to be a button, instead of just the top bar. Feel free to use his fiddle, as he edited mine. Alternatively, just put z-index:3; on the sidebar toggle class to make it fully clickable, from top to bottom.

Comment: lol, definitely a nice answer. I decided to just remap his CSS... cause that was dirty... [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/15/)

Answer (score 1):

**So, I have no idea what you're doing with your styling, but I got frustrated stumbling around it and came up with this. Hopefully you can work with it.**

## View Here: http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/15/

#### HTML

```
<div id="header"></div>

<div id="leftNav">
    <div id="toggler"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
* {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
#header {
    background:green;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}
#leftNav {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    background:#CCC;
    width:220px;
}
#toggler {
    position:relative;
    width:20px;
    height:100%;
    background:#111;
    margin-left:220px;
}
```

#### JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var sidebarStatus = false;
  $('#toggler').click(function() {
     if (sidebarStatus == false) {
      $('#leftNav').animate({
        marginLeft: "-220px",
        opacity: "1"
      }, 'fast');
      sidebarStatus = true;
    }
    else {
      $('#leftNav').animate({
        marginLeft: "0px",
        opacity: "1"
      }, 'fast');
      sidebarStatus = false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: If you feel this is an accepted answer, please accept it with the green checkmark next to the up/down vote.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out. I hope this is want you need.

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3n7p/12/)**

Changes:

**HTML**

```
<div class="framecontentLeft">
  <div class="innertube">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="sidebar-toggle"></div> <!--repositioned slidebar-->
```

**CSS**

```
    .sidebar-toggle {
      top: 0;
      left: 220px;
      width: 20px;
      height: 100%;
      background: blue;
      float:left;
      position:absolute;
      z-index:10;
}
```

**JQuery** - Added this.

```
if (sidebarStatus == false) {
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: "-220px"},'fast');
}else{
        $(this).animate({
            marginLeft: "-220px"},'fast');
}
```

Comment: @user3097736 This is essentially copied work; you should accept the other answer.

Comment: How is this different from the other answer?

Comment: @AliGajani you just answered earlier than me but no.

Comment: @Daedalus Yes I would.